# Compatibility of Z170 motherboards with Kaby lake processors

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, compatibility

Motherboard using Intel's Z170 chipset have been out since before the Kaby lake line of CPUs (7th generation core processors a.k.a. 7000 series) were out. In several online stores you still see them listed as supporting "6th generation" Intel core processors (6000 series). I have noticed that several forums claim that you can run Kaby lake CPUs on Z170; and others say you need a BIOS upgrade. (The socket is physically the same.)

So, which is it, among the following options:

1. Can't use Kaby lake's with Z170 boards at all
2. Always need a BIOS upgrade, which manufacturers don't pre-apply
3. Kaby lakes just run on Z170s out of the box
4. Depends on the manufacturer and/or the motherboard model (please elaborate if you can)

Answer (score 1):

In fact Kaby Lake microarchitecture is an 'Optimiation' of Skylake, as is [said by Intel](https://newsroom.intel.com/editorials/new-7th-gen-intel-core-processor-built-immersive-internet/). It remains the same lithography of 14nm since Broadwell with a slightly increased operatibg frequency. As has always been, processors of the same architecture family can share motherboards. For example all 6-series and all 7-series motherboards can handle both Sandy Bridge and Ivy Bridge. But when IVB initially came out, the slight difference in microinstructions requires different handling from SNB, thus demand a BIOS update. Usually new MBs manufatured   have up-to-date BIOS out-of-the-box, so those assembled *before* a suitable BIOS for Kaby Lake are in need of a update so they can run Kaby Lake, while those assembled *after* KBL is out don't necessarily need to be updated before they operate properly.

Comment: Are you saying this based on general knowledge (you gave a general and common-sense'y answer), or also specific experience with Z170 boards and Kaby Lake processors? Sorry for being pedantic but obviously it's a situation in which I need to err on the side of caution rather than having to find a "temporary CPU" for doing a BIOS upgrade.

Comment: Well I *am* giving a common-sense answer but the situation hasn't changed since more than 10 years ago so that I believe it's still applicable.

Comment: So +1 and thank you, but I'll hold out for someone to perhaps verify this for me from experience before I go out and buy anything. Or I'll ask the store people.

Comment: From the earliest thing that I know, a motherboard originally designed for Pentium 4 *can* run a Celeron D (for Pentium D dual-core CPUs it depends) with an up-to-date BIOS. Also one for Celerons (Conroe) can run Core 2 E6000 series (but no guarantee for Pentium dual-core E6000 series because they are 'too new' to some extent).

Comment: FYI, the earliest Pentium 4's were announced in 2000, with 82845 series being their corresponding chipsets and LGA 775 as their sockets. Those motherboards, provided that they are kept in good conditions, can run Celeron D 360 (2007) with their final version of BIOS. That could be the longest life span for a product family since millenium.